# Azure autoscale get latest application

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I have a build server for continuous building / integration that can automatically deploy the latest code base to production. If I want to use Azure's auto-scaling functionality, I need a way for a newly started server to get the latest production code when it starts. Is this possible, and if so, how do you do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it the same way that you do for the instances that are already up and running?

Comment: Since they're up and running, they'll be pushed the latest on build. When you bring a server up, it would somehow have to pull the latest build, no? (this is my first build server so maybe I'm doing it wrong)

Comment: I haven't built what you're building before, but in general I'd try to make it so that this scenario would work the same. That's just a matter of design for web services in general (b/c you never know when a hard drive is going to fail in a datacenter and force your vm/instance to new hardware). I suppose your new instance could set an "I'm alive!" flag in some well-known location.

Comment: is this azure paas or iaas ?